# Can I modify the text within a beautiful soup tag without converting it into a string?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am working on parsing a scraped webpage using BeautifulSoup and, as always, there are weird exceptions to the page's regular formatting.

What I have so far is a table, and I have gotten all of the rows into `rows`, and all of the columns into `cols` (which contains all of the `<td>`s) and then I get the plain text from the element to use later.

This looks like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table", {"class" : "election"})
rows = table.findAll("tr")
data =[]

for row in rows:
    cols = row.findAll('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]

data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values

return data
```

The problem is that sometimes, one of the `<td>`s contains several `<li>`s, and I want to preserve these  by replacing them with `\n`s. Right now, using the `.text` attribute of `ele` strips out all of the tags, including the `<li>`s.

My question is this: is it possible to use `.text` in a way which preserves only certain tags? I know I could convert the `ele` into a string first, but then I can't have beautiful soup automatically remove all of the other ugly tags.

Here is an example of the html where the `<td>` contains `<li>`s:

```
<td> November General Election Day.Scheduled Elections:
    <ul class="vtips">
        <li>Federal, Statewide, Legislative and Judicial Offices</li>
        <li>County Offices</li>
        <li>Initiatives and Constitutional Amendments, if applicable</li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

Right now, my code outputs:

```
u'November General Election Day.Scheduled Elections:Federal, Statewide, Legislative and Judicial OfficesCounty OfficesInitiatives and Constitutional Amendments, if applicable'
```

and I would like it to look more like:

```
u'November General Election Day.Scheduled Elections:\nFederal, Statewide, Legislative and Judicial Offices\nCounty Offices\nInitiatives and Constitutional Amendments, if applicable'
```

Comment: Please give an example html that demonstrates the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Just added some example html, sorry about that.

Comment: If all tags within <td> are to preserved, you can use ele.renderContents() instead of ele.text

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit my question again -- it would really be best if I could replace them with newlines (or any other character to be used as a delimiter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure what is the motivation behind this question, but here's the idea.

Find all `li` tags and [`insert()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert) a new-line character at the beginning of the contents.

Working example (I've added some other tags to the `td` to demonstrate the behavior):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<td> November General Election Day.Scheduled Elections:
    <b>My Test String </b>
    <ul class="vtips">
        <li>Federal, Statewide, Legislative and Judicial Offices</li><li>County Offices</li><li>Initiatives and Constitutional Amendments, if applicable</li>
    </ul>
    <p>New Paragraph</p>
</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for element in soup.td.find_all('li'):
    element.insert(0, '\n')

print soup.td.text
```

Prints:

```
November General Election Day.Scheduled Elections:
    My Test String 


Federal, Statewide, Legislative and Judicial Offices
County Offices
Initiatives and Constitutional Amendments, if applicable

New Paragraph
```

---

Here is how you can apply the solution in your case:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<table class="election">
    <tr>
        <td> November General Election Day.Scheduled Elections:
            <b>My Test String </b>
            <ul class="vtips">
                <li>Federal, Statewide, Legislative and Judicial Offices</li><li>County Offices</li><li>Initiatives and Constitutional Amendments, if applicable</li>
            </ul>
            <p>New Paragraph</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "election"})
rows = table.find_all("tr")

data = []
for row in rows:
    for element in row.select('td li'):
        element.insert(0, '\n')
    data.append([ele.text.strip() for ele in row('td')])

print data
```

Comment: Thanks, that's close to what I want, but the reason I am doing this is to put it into a mysql db. Is it possible to get an output which is close to the edit I just made, with the newline characters?

Comment: @ConorStrejcek newline characters in the current solution are preserved too, please recheck.

Comment: Sorry, I might have been unclear -- I was referring to the part of my question where I asked if it was possible to replace <li>s with newline characters as opposed to preserving them.

Comment: @ConorStrejcek ah, sure, sorry, give me a minute.

Comment: @ConorStrejcek I've edited the answer, please see if it is what you wanted.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but I am having trouble implementing it. I added to my code in my question to show that I'm not working with a BeautifulSoup Object anymore, which is making it confusing to me. I also updated the type of output I'm trying to get. I would also like the newline character to come before the <li> rather than after it. Let me know if you need more clarification. Thanks.

Comment: @ConorStrejcek ok, thanks. I've changed the solution to insert the new line at the beginning of each `li`. Also provided you an example, demonstrating how you can apply the solution in your case. Check it out.

Comment: I get a type error for this line: for element in row.select('td li'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. But when I do type(row) it gives me a BeautifulSoup Tag object...I can't figure out what is wrong

Comment: @ConorStrejcek make sure you are using `beautifulsoup4` package: watch the import `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't notice that. It works perfectly, except I am getting double newline characters, do you have any idea why that would be?

Comment: @ConorStrejcek well, this is because there are existing new-lines in the html. If I were you, I would create a separate issue for this so that more people can help you. Consider creating a separate SO question, but provide as much details as you can.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help, I'll mark your answer as the selected answer. Thanks again!